# jpos : problem in unpacking field 123 even though the field size is 999

Tags: jpos

in the packager DE-123 is defined as below

```xml
      <isofield
          id="123"
          length="999"
          name="RECEIPT FREE TEXT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
```

when i try to send below value , the transaction is accepted and processed

```
/VER/1//MSO/MSOID123//MTR/MTR123//MOI/MOI1234//TXD/15XJNE15//AQU/004016//TTY/PUR//ATI/ABC123//FLR/Y/
```

but when i try to process below getting the exception error , the difference is just adding one character between the above and the below. why i am getting this error even though the field size is 999

```
/VER/1//MSO/MSOID123//MTR/MTR123//MOI/MOI1234//TXD/15XJUNE15//AQU/004016//TTY/PUR//ATI/ABC123//FLR/Y/
```

Below is the exception, it says max is 100 .not able to see where it is picking up that value .

```xml
    <log realm="channel/127.0.0.1:50072" at="2020-05-25T19:23:58.919" lifespan="1ms">
      <receive>
        <iso-exception>
          org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 123 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 101 too long. Max: 100) unpacking field=123, consumed=246
          org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 123 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 101 too long. Max: 100) unpacking field=123, consumed=246
            at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:340)
            at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:468)
            at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:976)
            at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:746)
            at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:344)
            at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:76)
        </iso-exception>
        --- header ---
        0000  60 00 00 00 00                                    `....

        --- data ---
        0000  30 31 30 30 66 32 33 63  34 34 38 31 38 38 65 31  0100f23c448188e1
    0010  38 30 30 38 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  8008000000000000
    0020  30 30 32 30 31 39 34 31  31 33 35 35 30 30 30 31  0020194113550001
    0030  32 33 34 35 38 36 37 38  39 30 30 33 30 30 30 30  2345867890030000
    0040  30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30  31 30 30 30 35 32 35 31  0000001010005251
    0050  39 32 33 35 38 31 39 32  33 35 38 31 39 32 33 35  9235819235819235
    0060  38 30 35 32 35 31 39 30  36 37 33 39 39 38 31 32  8052519067399812
    0070  31 35 30 36 30 30 31 35  32 37 30 36 30 30 34 36  1506001527060046
    0080  30 31 32 35 30 35 32 30  31 39 32 33 35 38 57 31  01250520192358W1
    0090  51 39 39 39 39 39 32 35  32 33 33 30 36 35 20 20  Q9999925233065
    00a0  20 20 20 20 20 41 70 70  6C 65 20 4E 5A 20 47 43       Apple NZ GC
    00b0  53 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 53 79 64 6E 65  S          Sydne
    00c0  79 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 41 55 30 31 32  y          AU012
    00d0  54 34 32 30 37 30 31 30  33 32 31 30 30 33 36 30  T420701032100360
    00e0  32 30 31 30 32 35 31 30  34 30 30 36 36 30 30 30  2010251040066000
    00f0  33 36 32 30 30 30 31 30  31 2F 56 45 52 2F 31 2F  362000101/VER/1/
    0100  2F 4D 53 4F 2F 4D 53 4F  49 44 31 32 33 2F 2F 4D  /MSO/MSOID123//M
    0110  54 52 2F 4D 54 52 31 32  33 2F 2F 4D 4F 49 2F 4D  TR/MTR123//MOI/M
    0120  4F 49 31 32 33 34 2F 2F  54 58 44 2F 31 35 58 4A  OI1234//TXD/15XJ
    0130  55 4E 45 31 35 2F 2F 41  51 55 2F 30 30 34 30 31  UNE15//AQU/00401
    0140  36 2F 2F 54 54 59 2F 50  55 52 2F 2F 41 54 49 2F  6//TTY/PUR//ATI/
    0150  41 42 43 31 32 33 2F 2F  46 4C 52 2F 59 2F        ABC123//FLR/Y/
    
      </receive>
    </log>
    <log realm="MIG_NT2_EP6-server-7336.server.session/127.0.0.1:50072" at="2020-05-25T19:23:58.919">
      <session-error>
        <iso-exception>
          org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 123 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 101 too long. Max: 100) unpacking field=123, consumed=246
```

one thing noticed is Field 62 length is 100 .is it somehow considering the length from field 62

```xml
      <isofield
          id="62"
          length="100"
          name="INTERMEDIATE NETWORK FACILITY (INF) DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
```

package definition

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
            "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
            "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">
    
    <!-- CIS (EBCDIC) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->
    
    <isopackager>
      <isofield
          id="0"
          length="4"
          name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="1"
          length="16"
          name="BIT MAP"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP"/>
      <isofield
          id="2"
          length="19"
          name="PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER (PAN)"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="3"
          length="6"
          name="PROCESSING CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="4"
          length="12"
          name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="5"
          length="12"
          name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="6"
          length="12"
          name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="7"
          length="10"
          name="TRANSMISSION DATE AND TIME"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="8"
          length="8"
          name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING FEE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="9"
          length="8"
          name="CONVERSION RATE, SETTLEMENT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="10"
          length="8"
          name="CONVERSION RATE, CARDHOLDER BILLING"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="11"
          length="6"
          name="SYSTEMS TRACE AUDIT NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="12"
          length="6"
          name="TIME, LOCAL TRANSACTION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="13"
          length="4"
          name="DATE, LOCAL TRANSACTION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="14"
          length="4"
          name="DATE, EXPIRATION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="15"
          length="4"
          name="DATE, SETTLEMENT"
           class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="16"
          length="4"
          name="DATE, CONVERSION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="17"
          length="4"
          name="DATE, CAPTURE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="18"
          length="4"
          name="MERCHANT TYPE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="19"
          length="3"
          name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="20"
          length="3"
          name="PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER (PAN) COUNTRY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="21"
          length="3"
          name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="22"
          length="3"
          name="POINT-OF-SERVICE (POS) ENTRY MODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"  pad="true" />
      <isofield
          id="23"
          length="3"
          name="CARD SEQUENCE NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="24"
          length="3"
          name="NETWORK INTERNATIONAL ID"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="25"
          length="2"
          name="POINT-OF-SERVICE (POS) CONDITION CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="26"
          length="2"
          name="POINT OF SERVICE (POS) PERSONAL ID NUMBER (PIN) CAPTURE CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="27"
          length="1"
          name="AUTHORIZATION ID RESPONSE LENGTH"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="28"
          length="6"
          name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION FEE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="29"
          length="3"
          name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT FEE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="30"
          length="24"
          name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION PROCESSING FEE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="31"
          length="99"
          name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT PROCESSING FEE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="32"
          length="11"
          name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION ID CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="33"
          length="11"
          name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION ID CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="34"
          length="28"
          name="PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER (PAN) EXTENDED"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="35"
          length="37"
          name="TRACK 2 DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="36"
          length="104"
          name="TRACK 3 DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="37"
          length="12"
          name="RETRIEVAL REFERENCE NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="38"
          length="6"
          name="AUTHORIZATION ID RESPONSE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="39"
          length="2"
          name="RESPONSE CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="40"
          length="3"
          name="SERVICE RESTRICTION CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="41"
          length="8"
          name="CARD ACCEPTOR TERMINAL ID"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="42"
          length="15"
          name="CARD ACCEPTOR ID CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="43"
          length="40"
          name="CARD ACCEPTOR NAME/LOCATION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="44"
          length="25"
          name="ADDITIONAL RESPONSE DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="45"
          length="76"
          name="TRACK 1 DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="46"
          length="999"
          name="ADDITIONAL DATA - ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="47"
          length="999"
          name="ADDITIONAL DATA - NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="48"
          length="999"
          name="ADDITIONAL DATA - PRIVATE USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLBINARY"
          />
      <isofield
          id="49"
          length="3"
          name="CURRENCY CODE, TRANSACTION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="50"
          length="3"
          name="CURRENCY CODE, SETTLEMENT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="51"
          length="3"
          name="CURRENCY CODE, CARDHOLDER BILLING"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="52"
          length="8"
          name="PERSONAL ID NUMBER (PIN) DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY"/>
      <isofield
          id="53"
          length="48"
          name="SECURITY-RELATED CONTROL INFORMATION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLBINARY"/>
      <isofield
          id="54"
          length="120"
          name="ADDITIONAL AMOUNTS"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="55"
          length="999"
          name="INTEGRATED CIRCUIT CARD (ICC) SYSTEM-RELATED DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY"/>
      <isofield
          id="56"
          length="35"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="57"
          length="3"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="58"
          length="11"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="59"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="60"
          length="7"
          name="ADVICE REASON CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="61"
          length="26"
          name="POINT-OF-SERVICE (POS) DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="62"
          length="100"
          name="INTERMEDIATE NETWORK FACILITY (INF) DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="63"
          length="12"
          name="NETWORK DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="64"
          length="8"
          name="MESSAGE AUTHENTICATION CODE (MAC)"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY"/>
      <isofield
          id="65"
          length="8"
          name="BIT MAP, EXTENDED"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY"/>
      <isofield
          id="66"
          length="204"
          name="SETTLEMENT CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="67"
          length="2"
          name="EXTENDED PAYMENT CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="68"
          length="3"
          name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="69"
          length="3"
          name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="70"
          length="4"
          name="NETWORK MANAGEMENT INFORMATION CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="71"
          length="8"
          name="MESSAGE NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="72"
          length="999"
          name="MESSAGE NUMBER LAST"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="73"
          length="6"
          name="DATE ACTION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="74"
          length="10"
          name="CREDITS, NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="75"
          length="10"
          name="CREDITS, REVERSAL NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="76"
          length="10"
          name="DEBITS, NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="77"
          length="10"
          name="DEBITS, REVERSAL NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="78"
          length="10"
          name="TRANSFERS, NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="79"
          length="10"
          name="TRANSFERS, REVERSAL NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="80"
          length="10"
          name="INQUIRIES, NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="81"
          length="10"
          name="AUTHORIZATIONS, NUMBER"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="82"
          length="10"
          name="CREDITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="83"
          length="10"
          name="CREDITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="84"
          length="10"
          name="DEBITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="85"
          length="10"
          name="DEBITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="86"
          length="16"
          name="CREDITS, AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="87"
          length="16"
          name="CREDITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="88"
          length="16"
          name="DEBITS, AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="89"
          length="16"
          name="DEBITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="90"
          length="42"
          name="ORIGINAL DATA ELEMENTS"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="91"
          length="3"
          name="ISSUER FILE UPDATE CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="92"
          length="3"
          name="FILE SECURITY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="93"
          length="11"
          name="RESPONSE INDICATOR"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="94"
          length="7"
          name="SERVICE INDICATOR"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="95"
          length="99"
          name="REPLACEMENT AMOUNTS"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="96"
          length="999"
          name="MESSAGE SECURITY CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY"/>
      <isofield
          id="97"
          length="17"
          name="AMOUNT, NET SETTLEMENT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_AMOUNT"/>
      <isofield
          id="98"
          length="25"
          name="PAYEE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="99"
          length="11"
          name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION ID CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="100"
          length="11"
          name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION ID CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
      <isofield
          id="101"
          length="17"
          name="FILE NAME"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="102"
          length="28"
          name="ACCOUNT ID-1"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="103"
          length="28"
          name="ACCOUNT ID-2"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="104"
          length="100"
          name="TRANSACTION DESCRIPTION"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="105"
          length="16"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="106"
          length="16"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="107"
          length="10"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="108"
          length="10"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
      <isofield
          id="109"
          length="84"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="110"
          length="84"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="111"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR ISO USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="112"
          length="999"
          name="ADDITIONAL DATA - NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="113"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="114"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="115"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="116"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="117"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="118"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="119"
          length="999"
          name="RESERVED FOR NATIONAL USE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="120"
          length="999"
          name="RECORD DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="121"
          length="999"
          name="AUTHORIZING AGENT ID CODE"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="122"
          length="999"
          name="ADDITIONAL RECORD DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="123"
          length="999"
          name="RECEIPT FREE TEXT"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="124"
          length="999"
          name="MEMBER-DEFINED DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="125"
          length="999"
          name="NEW PIN DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="126"
          length="999"
          name="PRIVATE DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="127"
          length="999"
          name="PRIVATE DATA"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR"/>
      <isofield
          id="128"
          length="8"
          name="MESSAGE AUTHENTICATION CODE (MAC)"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY"/>
    </isopackager>
```

```
<log realm="channel/127.0.0.1:43976" at="2020-08-11T22:09:17.524" lifespan="2ms">
  <receive>
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 121 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 14 too long. Max: 11) unpacking field=121, consumed=265
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 121 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 14 too long. Max: 11) unpacking field=121, consumed=265
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:340)
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:468)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:976)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:746)
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:344)
        at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:76)
    </iso-exception>
    --- header ---
    0000  60 00 00 00 00                                    `....

    --- data ---
    0000  30 31 30 30 66 32 33 63  34 34 38 31 38 38 65 31  0100f23c448188e1
0010  38 30 30 38 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  8008000000000000
0020  30 30 38 30 31 36 35 31  32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39  0080165123456789
0030  31 30 31 35 35 34 30 30  33 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  1015540030000000
0040  30 30 30 30 31 32 30 30  30 38 31 31 32 32 30 39  0000120008112209
0050  31 37 32 32 30 39 31 37  32 32 30 39 31 37 30 38  1722091722091708
0060  31 31 32 31 30 35 35 34  39 39 38 31 32 31 35 30  1121055499812150
0070  36 30 30 37 35 31 39 30  36 30 30 34 36 30 31 31  6007519060046011
0080  31 30 38 32 30 32 32 30  39 31 37 43 49 42 53 32  10820220917CIBS2
0090  49 30 35 32 30 32 30 30  31 33 31 20 20 20 20 20  I0520200131
00a0  20 20 4D 54 46 43 49 42  4D 50 47 53 20 20 20 20    MTFCIBMPGS
00b0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  50 49 4D 50 52 49 20 20          PIMPRI
00c0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  45 47 30 32 38 54 34 32          EG028T42
00d0  30 37 30 31 30 33 32 31  30 39 32 30 33 31 32 35  0701032109203125
00e0  36 31 30 35 30 30 30 30  31 38 34 30 30 32 36 31  6105000018400261
00f0  30 32 35 31 30 30 30 30  36 36 30 30 38 31 38 34  0251000066008184
0100  31 31 30 31 37 20 20 20  20 30 31 34 39 30 34 39  11017    0149049
0110  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20

  </receive>
</log>
<log realm="MIG_NT2_EP6-server-7336.server.session/127.0.0.1:43976" at="2020-08-11T22:09:17.524">
  <session-error>
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 121 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 14 too long. Max: 11) unpacking field=121, consumed=265
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 121 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 14 too long. Max: 11) unpacking field=121, consumed=265
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:340)
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:468)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:976)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:746)
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:344)
        at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:76)
    </iso-exception>
  </session-error>
```

Comment: Please, show your entire packager definition, so we can try to reproduce your problem

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz added the full package definition

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error with the data and packager you shared, so, the packager you shared could no have been the one that gave you your erro, primary because it's binary based and the data seems to be ASCII based

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz added the raw message ,please see if you can help how to solve this

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz, thanks found the issue , it is in the another  packager in the channel which had the length 11 for the data element  121

Comment: Glad to hear, that's what I was pointing in my last comment, that the packager didn't match the behavior therefore it couldn't be the one you were using.